# Active Directory with multi factor authentication for an existing web application

Tags: c#, active-directory, asp.net-mvc-2, two-factor-authentication, principalcontext

Customer is asking for LDAP / Active Directory authentication along with OTP (one time password) / multi-factor authentication for an old existing web application written in (asp.net MVC2). Is this possible?

Currently, we are using PrincipalContext in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement for username, password validation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If they want it separate from AD authentication (i.e. AD auth + some other authentication), then you'll have to build your own second authentication mechanism. If they want multi-factor authentication build into the AD authentication (i.e. AD authentication doesn't authenticate you until you complete the second method) then it depends on your AD setup. If you're using Azure AD, then I think it's possible. If it's all on-prem, then I'm not sure.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Thank you for the comment. This is on-prem solution they are asking for..

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write it yourself. After you authenticate the user via Active Directory, you will have to trigger a second step to generate a code and send it to them, and have a page where they can type in the code to finish the authentication. You will have to decide how you will send it to them (email or SMS or phone call).

For SMS or phone call, you can use a service like [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com). They actually have an article about using [two-factor authentication with ASP.NET](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/two-factor-authentication-csharp-mvc), but you probably won't be able to plug in that code as-is to an older app like yours.

Microsoft also [has an article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity) about it, but it assumes you're using ASP.NET Identity, which you may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Its a legendary web app. MVC2 with Membership provider NOT Identity. It already has 2FA with membership provider. AD Authentication alone works. 

from conceptual level, Problem I have is how to block the requests after AD authentication is done. As per my understanding, once the AD authentication is done, session is created. Even though I show them 2FA page to enter the OTP, what if end user enter specific URL to access something else. Do I have write code at request level to verify whether 2nd factor also succeeded? Thanks again

Comment: Well it sounds like you are using  Forms Authentication, right? And you're just verifying the password with AD... so before you create the Forms ticket, you can add this second step in.

Comment: No we are using Windows Authentication. We also gave them an option with Forms Authentication with 2FA. Now they dont want Forms with 2FA, they rather want Windows with 2FA.

Comment: Oh I see. You said you were using `PrincipalContext` to authenticate, so that sounded like you were handling the authentication yourself. You will have to use Forms Authentication then, but you can still incorporate Windows Authentication so people are not prompted for their AD username/password. I just recently described how to do this [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57575030/1202807).