# Does LDAP return whether a user login was successful?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, response

Is it possible to retrieve information about LDAP authentication - whether it was successful or not?

I need to achieve the following scenario:

- User navigates to login page, where only logon using Active Directory is available
- If login was not successful, user will be redirected again to a login page, where also a secondary login option will become available

I know it is possible to retrieve information about user login history in Active Directory, but haven't find any info on whether it is possible to proceed in the way as I explained. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you want split Windows and Forms authentication. I've done this before, and I described how to do it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57575030/1202807

Comment: Tell us what you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does LDAP return whether a user login was successful?

Within LDAP, a BIND REQUEST is sent by the client and a BIND RESPONSE is returned by the LDAP Server.

If the client receives BIND RESPONSE of 0 then it is a successful, otherwise it is NOT.